# Nesting Lazy loaded modules in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I tried to lazy load a module2 from a module1 which itself was lazy loaded. The error I got was

> Cannot find primary outlet to load 'Module2Component'

which is a component inside module2. Is this possible? I am only using the primary router outlet.

Comment: Yes you can totally lazy load a module from a lazy loaded module. You must have forgotten a `router-outlet` in your HTML somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It is possible to lazy load nested modules, I re wrote my code and it works fine now. Must have had a typo somewhere.